# Different priority based on user in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have data which looks like this:

```
"-JnbxaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
      "Name":"Bill"
    },
"-yryexaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
      "Name":"Jill"
    },
"-6yrhxaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
      "Name":"John"
    },
"-gn643Jp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
      "Name":"Jack"
    }
```

When a user is logged in with id `simplelogin:5` I want to order the output based on their sort preferences.  So say for example user `simplelogin:5` previously set his order to `Jack,Jill,Joh,Bill` and `simplelogin:1` set their order to `Bill,John,Jack,Jill`.

I know I can set priority but that's priority for the data as a whole and it isn't tied to a user, this is shared data which needs custom priority per user.

I was thinking of setting up something like this:

```
users[
{
"uid":"simplelogin:1",
"nameOrder":[-gn643Jp3rgsIeM2O0EN, -yryexaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN, etc.]
}
];
```

But it seems like there should be a better way, and even if I was able to generate a list like that, i'm not sure how to sort the output to follow the order in the `nameOrder` entry.

Comment: One solution could be to store each user's sort preference under their user node. So something like: `/user-id/sort-preference/ascending`. Then you could use that to order names according to their preference. Could you provide the snippet of code you're using to sort right now?

Comment: I'm not sorting at all right now, I have a jQuery draggable list of all of the names, after the draggable sort is done I need to keep the sort persistent based on user.

Comment: Another example of this would be a shared todo list, different people sharing the todo list will order the todo's based on their own personal preference, i'm not sure if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to modify your main list with a persistent sort id. I used a numeric value but you can use whatever value you prefer.

```
"-JnbxaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
  "Name":"Bill",
  nameIndex": 0
},
"-yryexaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
  "Name":"Jill",
  "nameIndex": 1
},
"-6yrhxaJp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
  "Name":"John",
  "nameIndex": 2
},
"-gn643Jp3rgsIeM2O0EN" : {
  "Name":"Jack",
  "nameIndex": 3
}
```

Then store your user defined sort preference

```
"simplelogin:1" : {
  "nameOrder": "0,2,3,1"
},
"simplelogin:5" : {
  "nameOrder": "3,1,2,0"
}
```

Now when you read the name list, use the array index saved in nameOrder to display results.